# Correct epoch to DateTime conversion

Tags: php, datetime

Whit this code:

```
$epoch=  '1609455600';
$date = new DateTime( '@'.$epoch);
echo $date-> format( 'Y-m-d');
```

I see this result `2020-12-31`. The server timezone is reported as **Europe/Zurich** (with `date_default_timezone_get`). But in this time zone that date should be 2021-1-1.

What is going on here?

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) :     Note:

    The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the $datetime parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00). So you can try something like this :
 `echo $date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString($date->getTimeZone()->getOffset($date) . ' seconds'))->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Thanks @tuckbros. DateTime is weird

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment from @tuckbros. The output with var_export shows that the DateTime object has the time zone 00:00 (UTC).

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');
$epoch=  '1609455600';

$date = new DateTime( '@'.$epoch);

var_export($date);
/*
DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2020-12-31 23:00:00.000000',
   'timezone_type' => 1,
   'timezone' => '+00:00',
)) 
*/
```

The clean way to get the local time is to transfer the object to the desired time zone (and not to add any offset times).

```
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
var_export($date);
/*
DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'Europe/Zurich',
)) 
*/
```

You can now continue to work with the DateTime object, since it has the correct time zone in addition to the correct local time.